# Is futher a word?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I have a friend who presides over think tank discussions. As comments are being given on a given topic he will invariably ask before moving to next topic: " anything futher on this topic?"

I know farther is a word related to physical distance and further is a word related to deeper investigation of subject matter.

But futher is not an acceptable written or pronounced word is it?

Even here if you search futher you will find it in questions and answers.

Is it ever acceptable English form to write or say futher?

Comment: "Futher" is not an _English_ word. Your friend probably mislearnt it.

Comment: How can you be so sure it's not "further" that he meant?

Comment: @NVZ of course further is the appropriate word but futher is how he and others say the word and even write it is there some obscure reason that it can be acceptable

Answer (score 1):

The word your friend is saying is *further.*  You may have misheard it, or perhaps your friend mispronounced it.  Either way, his question has valid and proper grammar.

[Here is the definition from the Cambridge Academic Content Dictionary:](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/further)

> more, extra, or additional; comparative of far :  *Call your local library for further information.*

For further information, (see what I did there?) here is an article that goes into [farther versus further](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/farther-further/).

Comment: I got a notification that this question has been viewed 2500 times so your answer  has been as well. Never understood why it was closed as off topic.

Comment: 10,000 views  as of today I wanna thank my mom and dad and all my English teachers who helped me become the literary genius I am today